# Office Addin deployment for on-prem solutions for Office 365

Tags: office365, office-js, office-addins

We have created an Office Addin that is a client to inputting data into our on prem server. We have users that have on-prem servers that want this Office 365 addin.  How do we deploy this to them. Sideloading/Network Share is listed as being "development only" and Centralized Deployment requires Office 364 Pro Plus. Do you have to publish to AppSource and make it configurable? Want to be able to create custom options for our customers.

Answer (score 0):

Your customers can use a Network Share. It is not for development only. For another option, see this blog post: [Web add-in sideloader tool](http://theofficecontext.com/2020/03/23/web-add-in-side-loader-tool).

Comment: In their [Distribution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/publish) documentation  they just mention Sideloading as par to the development process so wasn't sure if it was usable as a production way to distribute.